# Duration.between with mocked Instants

Tags: java, scala, mockito

I am mocking Instants in my unit tests with mockito (org.mockito:mockito-core:4.7.0). The instants are mocked as expected (see screenshot).

[image]

Once I calculate the Duration of the 2 mocked Instants I get the following error:

> Cannot read field "seconds" because "end" is null

I thougt that the problem is, that the whole Instant class is mocked, so I additionally passed **Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS** so that the real implementation is used for the methods I do not mock:

```
val mock: MockedStatic[Instant] = mockStatic(classOf[Instant], Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)
```

Then I get the following error:

> class org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.ReflectionMemberAccessor
> cannot access a member of class java.time.Instant (in module
> java.base) with modifiers "private static"

MyClass.scala

```
class ClassToTest() {

  def run(): Duration = {
    val now = Instant.now()
    val now1 = Instant.now()
    Duration.between(now1, now)
  }

}
```

Test.scala

```
 @Test
  def test_duration(): Unit = {
    val testee = new ClassToTest()

      val timeMocked = Instant.parse("2022-08-31T08:55:48.200Z")
      val mock: MockedStatic[Instant] = mockStatic(classOf[Instant])
      try {
        mock.when(() => Instant.now()).thenReturn(timeMocked)
        val result = testee.run()
      } finally if (mock != null) mock.close()
  }
```

Comment: please show your whole Junit test

Comment: Please see updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to be funny: “The problem is not the problem. The problem is your attitude about the problem”.

What I meant to say is, your problem is not the *static* call to `now()`, but thinking that you should mock it.

From the Clock documentation:

> Best practice for applications is to pass a
> `Clock` into any method that requires the current instant. A *dependency
> injection framework* is one way to achieve this:
>
> ```
>    public class MyBean {
>      private Clock clock;  // dependency inject
>      ...
>      public void process(LocalDate eventDate) {
>        if (eventDate.isBefore(LocalDate.now(clock)) {
>          ...
>        }
>      }
>    }
> ```
>
> This approach allows an alternate clock, such as fixed or offset to
> be used during testing.

Now if you'll check the documentation for `Instant.now()` you'll see:

> Using this method will prevent the ability to use an alternate
> time-source for testing because the clock is effectively hard-coded.

```
public static Instant now() {
    return Clock.systemUTC().instant();
}
```

Luckily, `Instant` offers the alternative [Instant.now(Clock clock)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now-java.time.Clock-):

> Using this method allows the use of an alternate clock for testing.
> The alternate clock may be introduced using *dependency injection*.

```
public static Instant now(Clock clock) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(clock, "clock");
    return clock.instant();
}
```

By injecting a `Clock` in your design:

```
  class ClassToTest {

    val clock: Clock = Clock.systemUTC()

    def run(): Duration = {
      val now  = Instant.now(clock)
      val now1 = Instant.now(clock)
      Duration.between(now1, now)
    }
  }
```

You easily achieve what you want:

```
  "test" should {
    "should test duration" in {
      val testee = new ClassToTest {
        override val clock: Clock = mock[Clock]
      }

      val timeMocked = Instant.parse("2022-08-31T08:55:48.200Z")
      when(testee.clock.instant()).thenReturn(timeMocked)

      val result = testee.run()
      result shouldBe Duration.ZERO
    }
  }
```

Of course, if you still want to mock the static call to `now`, that is doable with *PowerMockito*, but I wouldn't go down that road, unless there are no better alternatives.

EDIT:
Since Mockito 3.4.0, this is also doable with *Mockito*, but their mocks have thread-local explicit scope. In this case, you need to mock `Duration.between` instead of `Instant.now`. The `null` issue is because `Duration.between` cannot calculate the duration between 2 mocks of `Instant.now()`.